# InstanceTree unavailable in the mobile version of the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a function who require the instanceTree of my model who works in the desktop browser.

```
instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
dbIds = getAllDbIds(instanceTree);
```

But in the mobile version of the viewer, the instanceTree from getData() seems to be missing for some reasons.

Do you know a way to access the instanceTree in the mobile viewer ?
Or is it possible to specify an option in the viewer to allow the mobile version to have access to it ?

I'm in the version v6 of the viewer

I tried in the v7 but it's the same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're unable to access the object tree of a model on a mobile device, you're likely hitting memory limits of the Forge viewer, and you can try to bypass those by explicitly setting the `memory.limit` config property to zero:

```
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(
    document.getElementById('viewer'),
    { memory: { limit: 0 } }
);
```

Comment: Rock on :) Cheers!