# Using browser on iPhone, the model in Forge Viewer cannot be completely loaded?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've tried using Chrome, Safari and Firefox browsers on iPhone to launch the Forge Viewer, but it seems that the model cannot be completely loaded.  I have a GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT in the code, but that code is never triggered.  And the Model Browser panel doesn't list out the model elements either - it seems like the data (attributes) of the model is not loaded.

The model is fairly large, is that the reason?  Is there any workaround?

Comment: Can you upload the model to GDrive/weTransfer/ Dropbox and drop the link to forge.help at autodesk.com so we can try to reproduce the issue? Chances are some requests to fetch large resources got timed out and the model never actually finished loading... Also Can you reproduce the issue on desktop?

Comment: Btw. this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236652/instancetree-unavailable-in-the-mobile-version-of-the-viewer/58236875#58236875.

Comment: @BryanHuang This issue does not happen on desktop - the model can be fully loaded on desktop browsers.  I've uploaded the model to WeTransfer and emailed the link to forge.help autodesk support.  Thanks!